# Creating a symbolic link not in the working directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hyperlink, console

the command usually works like a charm but this one `ln -si GIT/Settings/session ./.mozilla/firefox/foo.default/` just creates some kind of broken link shown as a file.

Why is that?

Even `sudo ln -fs` doesn't work.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Weird as it may sound,

```
ln -si ../../../GIT/Settings/session ./.mozilla/firefox/foo.default/
```

will do what you want.  The rule of thumb here is that you should specify your link targets relative to the location where you're placing the link.

On Unix and Unix-like file systems, a symbolic link is actually a special file whose contents are a path.  Typing `ln path filename` creates a symbolic link at *filename* whose contents are *path*.  So if, for instance, you type

```
ln foo bar/baz
```

then your system will create a link named bar/baz containing the path "foo".  That link, however, will be broken – when you try to dereference the link, your kernel dereferences it relative to the *link directory* – in this case, bar.  Your kernel will look for bar/foo, which does not exist.

If, on the other hand, you type

```
ln ../foo bar/baz
```

then your system will create a link named bar/baz containing the path "../foo".  Dereferencing this link, your kernel will look for bar/../foo, which does exist (and is in fact what you want).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the full path of the source and target file

```
ln -s (full path to /foo) (full path to bar/baz)
```